# Computer Architecture - D bytes and I bytes refer

Tags: architecture, mips, cpu-architecture

I have a homework and I have a table to fill it. In table heads are Instruction sets which refers to ISA-1, ISA-2, ISA-3 second one OPCODE (example load, store, add, sub), third one Operands which are x, y z, and 4th and 5th ones are I dont know which refers to I byte and D byte, what are they refers to.

In question below info were given.

The Opcode size is 1 byte
All register operands are 1 byte
All memory addresses are 2 bytes
All data values are 4 bytes
All instructions are an integral number of bytes in length

And example ISA code example is given below.

```
#this is ISA 1 example for MIPS code 
load y 
add z
store x
load x
add z 
store y
load x
sub y
store z
```

I tried to fill the table but I cant do that since I don't know what is D bytes and I bytes..

Table looks like below:

```
Instruction Sets | Opcode | Operands | I bytes | D bytes | Total Bytes |
ISA 1            | LOAD   |  Y       |  ?      |  ?      |  ?          |
```

Comment: All the bytes of the instruction are I.  All of the data values are D.

Comment: What are the exactly like opcode +operand can you give an example